# how to get GWT work with Grails 3

Tags: grails, gwt

I am using Grails latest version i.e 3.1.3, and GWT

I have gone through the gwt/grails plugin and their tutorials , but All of this is for old version of grails , where we had "BuildConfig.groovy" and the format looks different.

Now as we have build.gradle , I cant find a way to put gwt plugin there

What i have tried is :  adding

```
         compile "org.grails.plugins:gwt:1.0.2"
```

now when i run command:

```
           grails create-gwt-module
```

I get the exception:

```
            Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
 > Could not find org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.
Searched in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Users/Junaid/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/resources/1.2/r
 sources-1.2.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Junaid/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/resources/1.2/r
 sources-1.2.zip
    https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/resources/1.2/re
 ources-1.2.pom
    https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/resources/1.2/re
  ources-1.2.zip
Required by:
    helloworld2:helloworld2:0.1 > org.grails.plugins:gwt:1.0.2
```

this is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
}
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
    classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.5.0"
    classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:5.0.2"
}
```

}

```
 version "0.1"
 group "helloworld2"

  apply plugin:"eclipse"
  apply plugin:"idea"
  apply plugin:"war"
  apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
  apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
  apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

  ext {
  grailsVersion = project.grailsVersion
  gradleWrapperVersion = project.gradleWrapperVersion
 }

 repositories {
mavenLocal()
maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencyManagement {
imports {
    mavenBom "org.grails:grails-bom:$grailsVersion"
}
applyMavenExclusions false
}

dependencies {
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
compile "org.grails:grails-core"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate4"
compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache"
compile "org.grails.plugins:gwt:2.6.0"
console "org.grails:grails-console"
profile "org.grails.profiles:web:3.1.3"
runtime "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline"
runtime "com.h2database:h2"
testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"
 }

 task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
gradleVersion = gradleWrapperVersion
}

assets {
minifyJs = true
minifyCss = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to get `compile "org.grails.plugins:gwt:1.0.3"`, [the latest version of plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/gwt)?

And if it can't be downloaded automatically to download it manually from [repo](https://github.com/simplicityitself/grails-gwt/releases) and put in one of searched locations in your local maven repository?

In [official plugin docs](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/plugins.html) you can read:

> In Grails 2.x plugins were packaged as ZIP files, however in Grails
>   3.x plugins are simple JAR files that can be added to the classpath of the IDE.

So try to pack plugin to jar according to [official deployment docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/deployment.html):

> Another way to deploy in Grails 3.0 or above is to use the new
>   support for runnable JAR or WAR files. To create runnable archives,
>   run grails package:
>
> `grails package`

Comment: Thanks , I actually trace the http// searched location, https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/gwt/ ....  and there it was only 1.0.2, so i used that, and then it started giving this above error,   for the second solution I downloaded this zip file of plugin , not sure how to place it in that folder, should i put this whole unzipped folder there ...

Comment: According to communicates from your stacktrace place these files for version 1.0.2: `file:/C:/Users/Junaid/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/resources/1.2/resources-1.2.pom
    file:/C:/Users/Junaid/.m2/repository/org/grails/plugins/resources/1.2/resources-1.2.zip`

Comment: thanks , but i'll be needing a pom or .jar file ,to be place here , which i dont see in this zip file which i downloaded from this repo .

Comment: Did you try with 1.0.3 which I suggested?

Comment: Yeah , downloaded 1.0.3 zip , then i unzip the folder and place the whole folder in this local maven repo  :After that i get this error :   here the screenshot..     http://screencast.com/t/wVlFAyPWeQa