# GWT and GRAILS Command not found create-gwt-module

Tags: grails, gwt

I have created a helloworld grails project using grails 3

next i simply run this command

```
          grails create-gwt-module
```

and it just keep on saying:

```
          Error Command not found create-gwt-module
```

I found this command on many tutorials , but why it isnt working for me ..

Answer (score 0):

Use "grails help" to see all commands and "grails command help" to see what they do. See this page for [Grails documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Command%20Line/Usage.html).  To add GWT plugin add this line in dependencies in build.gradle file. But check "grails list-plugins" command and make sure this is the latest version. Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35822526/how-to-get-gwt-work-with-grails-3)

- compile "org.grails.plugins:gwt:1.0.3"

Comment: I don't think it will work. This plugin is for Grails 2 version. List of published plugins for Grails 3 is under http://grails-plugins.org/ and it seems there is no Grails 3 plugin for GWT